# How to handle common code using ember/ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What is the best way for handling common code using ember-cli?  We have a number of different projects but want to share a common set of components, view, templates etc.  In addition, each project will implement their own set of components, views, templates that are specific to the project.

Comment: I think you may want to look into ember-cli addons. http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/06/24/introducing_ember_cli_addons.html

Comment: @blessenm Yep, that looks like what I want, but I don't think it is released, it is just a concept.

Comment: I think there are a couple of addons. The whole story for it is slowly forming. Might want to follow the github page to find its progress.